# Looking for the possible remainders of X divided by 92

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $ \,x^2+46x-50 \equiv 0 \, (23) \quad \text{and} \quad $ $7x-15 \equiv 0 \, (4). \quad$
I got up to $x \equiv 1 \, (4)$ and $x^2 \equiv 4 \, (23)$. I could check the remainder of every possible $x$ divided by 23 to see in which cases $x^2$ divided 23 leaves remainder 4, but I don't think it is the right way to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

You have $x\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. This means $x = 4y+1$ for some $y$.

$$(4y+1)^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{23}$$

$$4y+1 \equiv \pm 2 \pmod{23}$$

$$4y \equiv -3\pmod{23}, 4y \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$$

$$y \equiv 5 \pmod{23}, y \equiv 6 \pmod{23}$$

$$x \equiv 21, 25\pmod{92}$$